# String to html element in email

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a string which includes html elements. For example:

`var thisString = "This string has html elements like <b>bold</b> and <u>underline</u>";`

I am trying to use this string in an email so that the word bold is actually bold and underline is underlined, rather than displayed as a string.

gs script file:

```
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Email');                                                                                                                                                                                                         
template.message = thisString;
var message = template.evaluate();
MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: toEmail,
      subject: 'Subject',
      htmlBody: message.getContent()
});
```

html file:

```
<html>
<?=message?>
</html>
```

The email is sent with body exactly as the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use force-printing to prevent Apps Script from escaping HTML.

```
<html>
<?!= message ?>
</html>
```